# bpy.ops.wm.addon_expand(module="module_name") works in console, but not in add-on

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, customization

My add-on shows the User Preferences view, selects the "Add-ons" tab and search for a specific add-on.

I'm trying to expand that add-on, but it doesn't work consistently. I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bl_info'
```

It works in console, though.

The code in question is this, where *xxx* is the name of the .py file or the add-on *folder*.

```
class XxxOperator(bpy.types.Operator):

    bl_idname = "xxx.configure"
    bl_label = "Show Plugin"

    def execute(self, context):
            bpy.context.user_preferences.active_section = 'ADDONS'
            window = bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
            bpy.data.window_managers["WinMan"].addon_search = "xxx"
            bpy.ops.wm.addon_expand(module = "xxx")
            return {'FINISHED'}
```

It's an option in the menu. The init file (I'll omit the bl_info and the imports):

```
class XxxMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_XxxMenu"
bl_label = "Xxx"

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator("xxx.submit", text="Submit")
    layout.operator("xxx.configure", text="Show Plugin")

def add_to_menu(self, context):
    self.layout.menu("OBJECT_MT_XxxMenu", icon = "PLUGIN");

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_render.append(add_to_menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_render.remove(add_to_menu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: BSE automatically makes inverted double quotes, even when the plain text of the title uses the right symbols. (just FYI no point editing the title, i tried)

Comment: are you getting " AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bl_info' "

Comment: Yes, I get that error. I edited the question, thanks.

Comment: Can we get the full script, and in which context it is used (e.g. is it a plain addon? a script to be executed from Text window? etc.)

Comment: Sorry, I can't share the full script (that sucks, I know), but I'll add more info in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Whether an addon is displayed expanded or not in the *User Preferences* is stored in the `bl_info` dictionary, in the property called `show_expanded`.

`addon_utils` manages a cache of addons. It uses the global `addons_fake_modules`. It can be used to determine and change the expand state:

```
import bpy
import addon_utils

# Get a module reference by name
mod = addon_utils.addons_fake_modules.get("space_view3d_3d_navigation")

# If found, expand it
if mod is not None:
    mod.bl_info['show_expanded'] = True

    # Find User Preferences area and redraw it
    for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
        for area in window.screen.areas:
            if area.type == 'USER_PREFERENCES':
                area.tag_redraw()
```

Note that running this code as part of an addon is tricky, see e.g.:

- http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/API_Changes#Restricted_Context
- https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/18134/1363

Answer (score 1):

from `startp/bl_operators/wm.py` the `WM_OT_addon_expand` operator gives a hint how to check if it is expanded or not:

```
class WM_OT_addon_expand(Operator):
    "Display more information on this addon"
    bl_idname = "wm.addon_expand"
    bl_label = ""
    bl_options = {'INTERNAL'}

    module = StringProperty(
            name="Module",
            description="Module name of the addon to expand",
            )

    def execute(self, context):
        import addon_utils

        module_name = self.module

        # unlikely to fail, module should have already been imported
        try:
            # mod = __import__(module_name)
            mod = addon_utils.addons_fake_modules.get(module_name)
        except:
            import traceback
            traceback.print_exc()
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        info = addon_utils.module_bl_info(mod)
        info["show_expanded"] = not info["show_expanded"]
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Thus.. i think something like this, you'll probably want to refine it

```
import bpy
import addon_utils

module_name = "sverchok"
addon_utils.modules_refresh()

bpy.ops.screen.userpref_show("INVOKE_DEFAULT")
bpy.context.user_preferences.active_section = "ADDONS"
bpy.data.window_managers['WinMan'].addon_search = "sverch"

try:
    mod = addon_utils.addons_fake_modules.get(module_name)
    info = addon_utils.module_bl_info(mod)
    if not info["show_expanded"]:
        info["show_expanded"] = True

except:
    import traceback
    traceback.print_exc()
```

it's just these lines really:

```
mod = addon_utils.addons_fake_modules.get(module_name)
info = addon_utils.module_bl_info(mod)
info["show_expanded"] = True  # or False to Collapse
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly what I have, and it doesn't work in my add-on.

Comment: When used in console it works, and if it's already expanded, it contracts it again.

Comment: But expand/unexpand was always the only problem... the rest of the code always worked fine.

EDIT: sorry, I didn't see your last answer. So the only problem now is to detect if the add-on was already expanded?

Comment: The bl_info error disappears if I delete the "addon_expand" line.

Comment: Actually, it's possible to detect if an addon is displayed expanded and can be toggled without an operator. See my answer for example code.