# Add-Ons - 3D View: Dynamic Context Menu

Tags: python, add-on

I have an issue with said add-on listed in the question title but the issue varies depending on Blender version used.

Blender Versions:

2.79 - Add-on appears to work as intended, so in essence this would be the control version to compare to when/where needed.

2.80 - Though I didn't test all the options to see what was and wasn't broken, there was one that I used a bit that was broken. That broken bit would be the following: Space, Snap Cursor, Cursor to Edge Intersection. In simple terms the error being that on line 2945 **"layers_local_view"** isn't used anymore in 2.8 and I tried various methods to try to change it to fix it but got a specific error message about matrix and etc. Plus I tried to use a snippet of what was changed from the 3.3.1 version into the 2.8 version but that didn't work either in which it still brought up that specific error message.

3.3.1 - I would have used this version to test if **"Cursor to Edge Intersection"** works but I can't even do that. The add-on is there in the add-ons file folder but when going to preferences add-on, its not there in the checkmark menu. I also tried to see if that was the issue for 3.2 and yeah its not in the preferences add-on section for there either.

Does anyone have a python code fix for what was mentioned in versions 2.8 and 3.3.1 or know of a version other than 2.79 where the add-on does work. I don't want to have to go back and forth between 2.79 and a newer version unless need be seeing as how some stuff just disappears or gets orphaned between specific versions, in which case I just have to export stuff out and import it back in when going from version to version where need be.

Side note, I do like a lot of the new features from 2.8 and up but I just wish the add-ons in general were fully fixed when they released the major 2.8 update. As is I did see that some of the 2.8 update changes were applied to the **"Dynamic Context Menu"** but some stuff was missed like the issue already mentioned up above about the **Cursor to Edge Intersection**. Plus further changes were made to it at some point where the large file was divided out into multiple files as seen in Blender versions 3.2 and 3.3.1 though whatever was changed in that might have contributed to it not appearing in the add-ons menu section for those Blender Versions.

Also the addon file is labeled - **space_view3D_spacebar_menu.py** - when looking at versions 2.79 or 2.8 but when looking for it in 3.2 or 3.3.1 it will be in the folder labeled the following: **space_view3D_spacebar_menu**

Comment: There are no Blender developers or programmers here. If you think there's a bug in a built in addon you should report it via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu. The manual section on that addon is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/interface/context_menu.html#dynamic-context-menu).

Comment: See the Note section in the Blender manual to activate the addon as the Spacebar is normally used for other actions nowadays. Searching for 'Dynamic' in Preferences > Addons certainly finds it here in Blender 3.3.1.

Comment: @JohnEason thanks for the reply with your comment/answer. Though you should put your reply as an answer so I can upvote it. Thing is I didn't know they renamed the addon for the checkmark menu for version 3. Also the function works as intended in that Blender version, thanks. Oh and side note, there are programmers here, I could even point to several question titles such as - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32141/bpy-ops-wm-addon-expandmodule-module-name-works-in-console-but-not-in-add-o?rq=1

Comment: I meant that there are no programmers who work for the Blender Foundation here. I realise that there are Python programmers here. I don't think my comments are really suitable as an answer as they were really just suggestions.

Comment: @JohnEason Well I could be wrong but I remember in the past reading that the add-ons are community contributions. As for how all of that gets ok'd / reviewed to be part of the official release, I couldn't say. Either way, you or I could just as easily edit the python code for the add-ons to improve upon it or make our own versions of. Also it wouldn't exactly matter if Blender Foundation programmers ask or answer questions here, but it would be neat if they did but that wasn't the question. As is, your comment does answer the question, so I was suggesting that you put it as an answer.